# No protocol specified on CentOS 8.2.2004 with Oracle Database EE 19c when trying to run netmgr

Tags: oracle, centos, x11

I'm trying to install oracle 19c database on a new installation of CentOS 8.2.2004 (from CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-dvd1.iso) in vmware workstation.

I've basically done the following as root..

```
yum install -y gcc-c++
yum install -y ksh
yum install -y sysstat
yum install -y xorg-x11-utils
yum install -y libnsl
yum install -y libaio-devel
yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And installed oracle database...

```
rpm -Uvh /home/phil/Downloads/oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then as the oracle user created by the oracle-database-preinstall, tried to run netmgr (to configure a listener) but it doesn't run. I am running it all locally in the vm desktop in a terminal window (so not connecting remotely).
This is what I get with some helpful diagnostics..

```
oracle@localhost bin]$ ./netmgr
No protocol specified
Exiting
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.BufferedApplet.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.client.appContainer.WebApplication.<init>(WebApplication.java:752)
    at oracle.net.mgr.container.NetApplication.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.client.appContainer.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:3316)
[oracle@localhost bin]$ xhost +
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
[oracle@localhost bin]$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
[oracle@localhost bin]$ yum list installed | grep x11
dbus-x11.x86_64                                    1:1.12.8-10.el8_2                             @AppStream   
libxkbcommon-x11.x86_64                            0.9.1-1.el8                                   @AppStream   
pulseaudio-module-x11.x86_64                       11.1-23.el8                                   @AppStream   
xorg-x11-drv-fbdev.x86_64                          0.5.0-2.el8                                   @AppStream   
xorg-x11-drv-libinput.x86_64                       0.29.0-1.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-drv-vesa.x86_64                           2.4.0-3.el8                                   @AppStream   
xorg-x11-drv-vmware.x86_64                         13.2.1-8.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64                         1:7.5-40.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch                        7.5-19.el8                                    @AppStream   
xorg-x11-server-Xorg.x86_64                        1.20.6-3.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-server-Xwayland.x86_64                    1.20.6-3.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-server-common.x86_64                      1.20.6-3.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-server-utils.x86_64                       7.7-27.el8                                    @AppStream   
xorg-x11-utils.x86_64                              7.5-28.el8                                    @AppStream   
xorg-x11-xauth.x86_64                              1:1.0.9-12.el8                                @AppStream   
xorg-x11-xinit.x86_64                              1.3.4-18.el8                                  @AppStream   
xorg-x11-xkb-utils.x86_64                          7.7-27.el8                                    @AppStream   
[oracle@localhost bin]$
```

I can run xterm, it opens up a new terminal window.
I don't have a ~/Xauthority file.
I've tried various values for DISPLAY, including

```
localhost:0  
localhost:0.0  
:0.0
```

I get a similar problem running ./runInstaller

```
[oracle@localhost dbhome_1]$ ./runInstaller 
ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.
No protocol specified

Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I've tried this on vmware workstation AND virtual box.
I've also tried this on Oracle Linux 7

..Same problem, Nothing works :(

Any ideas?

Regards, Phil Wilkinson

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your immediate problem, but you don't need to run netmgr to configur a listener.  Just start the listener with 'lsnrctl start'.  It will happily start with all default values, which is sufficient  for 99+% of all cases.

Comment: Hi EdStevens, thanks for your comment. I tried this and yes it ran successfully but I do need to configure a listener as it is required for the sucessfull installation of Siemens Team Center, which is the next goal. I've tried manually configuring a .ora file (the result of netmgr) without success.
So my main reason for asking is to get the oracle installation at 100% working, and that means getting the oracle gui tools working.

Comment: What, specifically, is it about Siemens Team Center that requires non-default configuration of the listener?

Comment: Hi Ed, thats another problem, I'd like to solve this oracle installation issue first.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need GUI, use `nmtui` CLI command to configure your network.

Or use the more complicated `nm` command.

If you need GUI, install the GUI packages first, before installing Oracle DB.

Here are the [instructions](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-gui-on-centos-8-minimal-cli-server/) to install GUI, on Centos.

Note that you installed `Centos 7` libraries above on `Centos 8` machine.

```
yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks Dudi Boy,  
I am running CentOS8 with the gnome desktop, so a gui is installed.  
Those are the latest compat* packages and there is no centos/8 folder.  
I'd also like to run dbca, which gives..  

`No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)`

  
So I could use cmd line but prefer gui to working, else not 100% confident in installation of oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I found some installation instructions that were specific to installing oracle19c on CentOS8 (and much simpler)..

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_8&p=oracle19c&f=6

..and now netmgr works after installing the oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

So I can only conclude that the instruction I was following screwed up x windows somehow.

[update]

I think the crux of my problem was that xhost + didn't work when I su root..

```
[root@tc12linux infodba]# xhost +
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
```

so I dismissed it as not a solution to the 'no protocol' problem, but when I did it from my 'admin' user...

```
[infodba@tc12linux ~]$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

...It did!

And now I am able to launch netmgr and dbca without issue. I just wish I had a better error message to start with. Oh well, thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest you install Oracle 19c on Centos 8 yet, Oracle doesn't fully support RHEL 8 completly.

However, this is a usefull guide for installation on OL7 and even Centos/OL 8
https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/articles-19c#database-19c-installations

Ps
I've never tried Oracle Installation thru rpm package you used, I suggest a clean and standard Oracle Installation